# Why in Javascript (1,2) equals 2?

Tags: javascript

I recently discovered that `(1,2)` equals `2`

Same for `(1,3,4) => 4` always return the last number

What is this expression exactly? It's not an array, not an object, what is it ?

Comment: Because of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: It's the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

Comment: *"The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and **returns the value of the last operand**"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code within parentheses is evaluated as an expression. Several expressions can be grouped together by using a `comma`. Commas are not just syntax for dividing arguments or function parameters, they double as an `operator` - much like `+`, `-`, etc serve multiple purposes, so does `,`

In the case you've outlined `(1,2)` the grouped expressions are obviously `1` and `2`. They are both evaluated to themselves, but when expressions are grouped by comma operators, only the last evaluated expression is returned.

This means:

`(1,2) == 2`

and:

`(1,2,3,4) == 4`